# PHP e-commerce system circular dependency issue

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, loose-coupling

I'm just getting started with dependency injection and I have immediately hit a problem: I have two classes that depend on each other.

The classes are Basket and Shipping.
In my Basket class I have the following relevant methods:

```
public function totalShipping()
{
    return $this->_shipping->rate();
}

public function grandTotal()
{
    return $this->totalProductsPrice() + $this->totalShipping();
}

public function totalWeight()
{
    $weight = 0;
    $products = $this->listProducts();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $weight += $product['product_weight'];
    }

    return ($weight == '') ? 0 : $weight;
}
```

`$this->_shipping` is an instance of the Shipping class

In my Shipping class I have the following relevant methods:

```
public function rate()
{   
    if (isset($_SESSION['shipping']['method_id'])) {
        $methodId = $_SESSION['shipping']['method_id'];
        return $this->_rates[$methodId]['Shipping Price'];
    }

    // Method not set
    return NULL;
}

// Available Methods depend on country and the total weight of products added to the customer's basket. E.g. USA and over 10kg
public function listAvailableMethods()
{   
    $rates = array();

    if (isset($_SESSION['customer']['shipping_address']['country_code'])) {
        foreach ($this->_rates as $method_id => $rate) {
            if (($_SESSION['customer']['shipping_address']['country_code'] == $rate['Country']) && ($this->_basket->totalWeight() > $rate['Weight From']) && ($this->_basket->totalWeight() < $rate['Weight To'])) {
                $rates[$method_id] = $rate;
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

`$this->_basket` is an instance of the Basket class.

I am totally clueless as to how to resolve this circular dependency. Thank you for your help in advance.

### Update

In my Shipping Class I also have this method:

```
public function setMethod($method_id)
{
    // A check to make sure that the method_id is one of the provided methods
    if ( !array_key_exists($method_id, $this->listAvailableMethods()) ) return false;

    $_SESSION['shipping'] = array(
        'method_id' => $method_id
    );
}
```

Comment: As a workaround I have changed the listAvailableMethods() to listAvailableMethods(Basket $basket) and passed the Basket at this point rather than at class initialisation. Is this acceptable?

Comment: It appears to me, that the listAvailableMethods function belongs in the Basket class, not the Shipping class. Then, there would be a clear relationship of the Basket using Rates, but never the other way around.

Comment: @RyanLaBarre At first I thought this was a brilliant solution but then I realised my setMethod function in my Shipping Class uses the listAvailableMethods() function :(

Comment: I guess I could move both of the functions over.. it just seems odd.

Comment: Could that one also be moved to the Basket? They both seem like functions which are dependent on the specific User's session info and related to the contents of their own basket / personal info. I would imagine that it'd be best to limit the Shipping class to general Shipping data which is not specific to the current session. It should just return the correct rates, etc for any given shipping method and address passed into it, without needing an instance of anything specific instantiated within it.

Comment: I think you are definitely on the right track here! I think possibly I need an extra class. Something like ShippingMethods and rename Shipping to Rates. If you would like to post any answer of sorts I will certainly accept it! Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: In general, when I've done similar things, I have a static rates class with ALL of the possible rate information, which has functions which accept shipping location and method information in order to return the available options. So you're on the right track with that idea. Just keep at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up renaming `Shipping` to `Shipping_Methods` and I have created a new class called `Customer_Shipping_Methods`. Essentially `Customer_Shipping_Methods` could be part of the `Basket` class but I'd rather keep it separate.

@RyanLaBarre was totally right. I was essentially mixing methods that should have been in the `Basket` Class with methods in my `Shipping_Methods` class. `Shipping_Methods` should have only contained general shipping data methods which were not specific to the current session.

I think what threw me, was that `Shipping_Methods` sources its data from a csv file rather than a database table. Once I started seeing `Shipping_Methods` as just another table, it all clicked in my mind.

@rdlowrey that is very good advice. I will be putting my session globals into my controllers immediately!